# compare keys of two dictionaries. if keys are matched then copy those key, values to file in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to compare keys of two dictionaries and if keys are matched then copy those key, values to file.

here the requirement is I have two files and I want to read all keys which are not starting with `#` and store it in two dictionaries. then compare two dictionaries keys.

lets say I have first file keys in `dict1` and second file keys in `dict2` and I want to compare `dict1` keys with `dict2` keys if `dict1` keys are matched with `dict2` keys then copy the value of matched key from `dict1` to `dict2`. The order of key values should not be changed in the file.

Below is the way I have followed but it doest meet my requirement.

```
with open(file1) as bl_file:
    content_bld_file = bl_file.readlines()
for i in content_bl_file:
    if '#' not in i:
        bl_d = {}
        bl_var1 = (i.split("="))
        if len(bl_var1)>1:
            bl_d[bl_var1[0]]=bl_var1[1]
        if len(bl_d) == 1:
            for k, v in bld_d.items():
                bl_file_keys = k
                print(bl_file_keys)

with open(file2) as tr_file:
    content_tr_file = tr_file.readlines()
for i in content_tr_file:
    if '#' not in i:
        tr_d = {}
        tr_var2 = (i.split("="))
        if len(tr_var2)>1:
            tr_d[tr_var2[0]]=tr_var2[1]
        if len(tr_d) == 1:
            for k,v in tr_d.items():
                tr_file_keys = k
                print(tr_file_keys)
```

so from the above I can able to read and store keys in two dictionaries but could not able to compare. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please be more specific as for what "does not meet requirements" mean? What is your output?

Answer (score 1):

You can update `dict2` with `dict1`'s values of the intersection of keys of the two dicts:

```
d1 = {1: 2, 3: 4}
d2 = {3: 5, 4: 3}
d2.update((k, d1[k]) for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys())
```

`d2` would become:

```
{3: 4, 4: 3}
```

Comment: If there are new keys in the d1, then those key values also should be added to second file

Comment: Very nicely Done. :+1:

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the intersection of the keys. Try this:

```
a = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
b = {1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7}
a_keys = set(a.keys())
b_keys = set(b.keys())
print(a_keys.intersection(b_keys))  // Prints {1, 3}
```

To find keys that are in one set but not in the other, just subtract them:

```
new_keys = a_keys - b_keys
```

Comment: If there are new keys in the d1, then those key values also should be added to second file

Comment: @dubru I added how to find new keys